# Shared Object Pool with out blocking for thread operations

Tags: java, multithreading, pool

Scenario:
Object of class A are created by the thread 1, And pass those objects to thread 2.
Thread 2 process those object and release.
[image]

I need to implement object polling mechanism for above scenario, Such as Both thread 1 and 2 have  thread local pools. Thread 1 retrieves the object from its pool and thread 2 returns the objects to pool of thread 2. In addition to that there is a global pool shared by both threads.
If pool of thread 1 is empty it retrieves object from the global pool, and once the pool of thread 2 is full it will release object to global pool,

My ultimate idea is objects are recycled through both threads.

Can you suggest any object pooling libraries to achieve this requirement ?

Comment: Try to code your scenario using java.util.Queue interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for your pools. In that code you can comment places, where you uncertain or simply don't know how to implement certain behaviour.

Comment: I am already implementing this as separate library. But i need to do i reinventing this ? Since most of common use cases are available as free and open source in java

Comment: I thought you ask about libraries for implement pools, using which you could code you scenario. Do you ask about library, which implement **entire** scenario? You draw connection `Global Pool -> Local Pool1`, but don't describe it. From the other side, you write "If pool of thread 2 is empty it retrieves object from the global pool", but connection "Global Pool->Thread2" is not drawn.

Comment: upvote for sketch ;-)

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I corrected the scenario inline. Yes, I am asking for a library or a framework to fulfill entire scenario with minimum locking.

Comment: @Janaka: Yes, scenario become more clear. You write, that "thread 1 retrives object from its pool" and "If pool of thread 1 is empty it retrieves object from the global pool", but **who fill LocalPool1?** If no one fill it, it is simpler to drop this pool, and retrieve objects directly from global pool.  Similar question about other local pool: **who consume objects from LocalPool2**?